# Symfony2 Twig extension

Tags: php, templates, symfony, twig

I have some problem to implement twig extension. I need to create my own filter (a substr filter). So I have thought to use twig extension.

I created a folder named "Extension" on MyApp\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\ and file :
WebsiteExtension.php

```
namespace Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Extension;

class WebsiteExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

    public function getFilters() {
        return array(
            'substr'  => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'substrFilter'),
        );
    }

    public function substrFilter($sentence, $start, $end) {
        return substr($sentence, $start, $end);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'website_extension';
    }
}
```

Then on my config.yml on /app/config

```
services:
    Website.twig.extension:
        class: MyApp\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Extension\WebsiteExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

But error occurs :

```
"Fatal error: Class 'MyApp\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Extension\WebsiteExtension' not found in .../appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1391"
```

It's strange because file and class exists ... I have missed something but what ?

Comment: Did you add the MyApp namespace to autoload.php?

Comment: @igorw i have 'MyApp' => __DIR__.'/../src', it's enough ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace this

```
namespace Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Extension;
```

By this

```
namespace MyApp\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Extension;
```

And for what your need dir `Bundle/WebsiteBundle`?
Is `Bundle` is not enough?

Your can see here how I implement this
https://github.com/azat/blog/blob/master/src/Blog/WebBundle/Twig/Extension/WebExtension.php

Comment: I will try this. But i can't change the structure of directory, it's not a personal project :'(

Comment: Ha thx it's working now ! I have lake of knowledge in php namespace I will learn more about it

Comment: Hi @azat, where do you put this file -- in `Acme/DefaultBundle/Extension` ?

Comment: Here MyApp/Bundle/WebsiteBundle/Extension