# symfony2 twig whitelist html tags

Tags: html, templates, escaping, symfony, twig

I pass a variable to my twig template in Symfony2, this variable may contain `<br />` html tags, I have tried to create an extension (function), but the variable still gets escaped.

How can I output a twig variable that allows the `<br />` tag? Is there a simple solution to just allow a whitelist of allowed tags in certain templates?

I've searched about twig sandboxes, but I'm not sure if that is my solution.

**edit:** I still want the variable to be escaped, but to allow exclusively the `<br />` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I thought it should be possible to write custom escaper strategies so you could do something like this:

```
{{ var|escape('html-custom') }}
```

Unfortunately it's not the case. Only available strategies are html and js. They're hard coded in the `twig_escape_filter()` function defined in a `Twig_Extension_Core` class file.

It seems that your only option is to write custom estension with a new filter:

```
{{ var|raw|customescape }}
```

Here's an example of custom twig extension and how to register it in Symfony: [Symfony2 Twig extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991925/symfony2-twig-extension)

Comment: sorry for the late response. Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to create a custom twig extension to allow <br> tag to be display as @Artem L answered below.

Comment: @gabrielem How's stripping BR tags will let them to be displayed? The question was about whitelisting tags, not blacklisting them.

Comment: @JakubZalas by insert a tag in the striptags function you are going to "whitelisting" it. And the BR tag will be displayed, no other tags. And this is a correct answer for the question. You just need to use the function striptags as it is. ;)  and how "Artem L" answered below.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I forgot the second argument to strip_tags() is actually a white list.

Answer (score 44):

Actually, you can use native PHP function strip_tags by following:

```
{{ var|striptags('<br>')|raw }}
```

you can allow multiple tags with following code:

```
{{ var|striptags('<br><p>')|raw }}
```

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between escape and striptags in that escape will make the tags harmless by replacing the <> with html entities, whereas striptags will remove the tag completely. So this would not be a good strategy if e.g. you want to allow most HTML but escape the <script>-tag

Comment: I also think this is the best answer. If you looking to allow some HTML in you script but still keep it safe, you need to work with a white list

Comment: Ain't the 'raw' making it unsafe here?

Answer (score 3):

You can do like that :

```
{{ text | striptags('<p><b><br') | raw }}
```

For instance,

```
<br>
```

won't escape

```
<br> and <br />
```

and

```
<p>
```

won't escape

```
<p> and </p>
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ var|striptags('<br>')|raw }}
```

works fine, but I don't know how to pass an array to the strip_tags php function with this twig filter.

both

```
{{ var|striptags(['<br>', '<b>'])|raw }}
```

and

```
{% set allow = ['<br>', '<b>'] %}
{{ var|striptags(allow)|raw }}
```

throw an "Array to string conversion" exception during the rendering of a template.

Be also carefull that strip_tags php function doesn't escape html attribute like "onclick".

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ var|nl2br }}
```

and/or

```
{{ var|raw|nl2br }}
```

[nl2br reference](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/nl2br.html)

Comment: I don't see a point of using `{{ var|raw|nl2br }}` since `{{ var|raw }}` already allows to uses anything (well yeah, except `\n`) but the answer `{{ var|nl2br }}` is brilliant since it keeps in place symfony's autoescape but allows to add easily `<br>` +1

Comment: nl2br filter is also a nice answer, when you consider having newlines instead of br-tags in your string.