# symfony2 twig escaping < character

Tags: html, symfony, escaping, twig

I am confused.

Input : `Sentence with <character`

My code:

```
{{ Status.StatusStatus }}
```

Output:

```
Sentence with <character
```

Which is good... but i need to enable the "anchor html" like "

```
<a href='/app_dev.php/something/' class='showProfile green bold'>something </a>
```

So i modify the code as: `{{ Status.StatusStatus|raw }}` what fixed the anchor problem and now is "converted" - clickable but from that input i get that output:

```
Input : Sentence with <character

Output: Sentence with
```

Any ideas how to allow `<something` situation?

Comment: You can't have a string which is half HTML and half text.  You need to use escape characters in the string to make it legal HTML.

Comment: If you need to add html elements from your variable, you need to use the `raw` filter like you did, but then you have to escape the special characters. So for example, `<` becomes `&lt;`.

Comment: hmm you dont talk about something like this right? raw|escape because this will not work obv. Or i get it the wrong way?

Comment: Since you've tagged your question with Symfony2, I assume you are using it. So quoting the documentation: [`escaping is on by default`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#output-escaping)

Comment: Yes i do. And i know the escaping is on by default but i am not sure how this can help me. Probably when stackoverflow works this way as well ... is a good idea to denied users to write code like < (no space here)sentence? as said sLaks "You can't have a string which is half HTML and half text."

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you write your TWIG to have the HTML markup you need, and print varaibles where you need

```
<a href="{{ path('route_name') }}" class="showProfile green bold">{{ Status.StatusStatus }}</a>
```

Comment: Its not, because {{ Status.StatusStatus }} contains the anchor link

Comment: That's bad view design, IMO

Comment: why bad? Hmmm and how else would i do it? i am opened to suggestions. I have classic status form... user submit some status like: This is my status. I would like to tag @peter in it. And i do convert it (@peter) into link and then display it with the rest of the status text.

Comment: Your variables (as passed in from the Controller) should not contain markup - that is a basic principle of the separation of concerns that MVC introduces. Use macros or a Twig Extension with functions/filters instead (I think a custom filter is your best bet for this scenario)

Comment: you mean something like: {{ myStatus|convertTagHashToAnchorUrl }} ?

Comment: Yup. There's a brief how-to here, which has a link to the in-depth documentation at the bottom. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: hmm but i have already function like that. I just wanted to create the question shorter so i did not put it there. This is exactly how i have it already: {{ Status.StatusStatus|cleanSpaces|makeUrls|striptags("<a>")|raw }}. But i think it will be the best to just deny sentences like: < something(together)

Comment: Are you using the appropriate escaping options in your filter? There's `is_safe` and `pre_escape` values that can effect what your filter returns.

Comment: I did not modify any of these. So i have the default safe values. I guess i would like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own twig extension to whitelist some html Elements:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8026130/1847340