# Twig 1.x escaper - allow custom tags by default

Tags: symfony, twig

Using the latest Twig 1.x and need to escape everything by default except some HTML tags. Found old solution at [symfony2 twig whitelist html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000642/symfony2-twig-whitelist-html-tags/8026130) which works great.

Unfortunately, most of my variables contain basic HTML tags; therefore, it would take lots of time to write code like this - `{{ var_name|striptags("<some_html_tags>")|raw }}` - for each variable in template.

Is there a way to easily allow specific tags by default (without writing custom extensions, etc.)? Twig documentation has entries about escaper extension (https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.x/api.html#escaper-extension), so I guess this one should work somehow?

However, trying to add code like:

```
$escaper=new Twig_Extension_Escaper("html", 'striptags("<some_html_tags>")|raw');
```

didn't work for me.

Comment: Good one im interested in the solution of this question. Its a hell to put in everything by hand. 

Im also prety sure u can write an extention that does this. But no clue how to do it.